# How does XCode install created target to iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, simulator

I am writing makefile to buil XCode project. I have got done everything except install iphone-simulator-target to iPhone Simulator?

I found that iPhone Simulator put all applications to ~/Users/wangjian/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications, but the next fold is 399E3422-F07E-40B5-8EEC-C8B9D05F39EB. Is xcode or simulator generate this fold? how can I do this with command line

Answer (score 0):

It's a [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier). You can install [ossp-uuid](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/lib/uuid/) using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) if you want to generate that yourself.